# MongoDB update Document with upsert as criteria in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongotemplate

I have to update doc according to a criteria or add one when the doc does not exist i.e. upsert depends upon exists query. I can achieve that in mongoDb shell but have no idea how to achieve the same with mongoTemplate in Java.

my query is

```
db.Bookmark.update( { $and:[ 
      { 'clientId':168613 }, 
      { 'resourceId':76864136 }, 
      {'books':{ $not: {$size :3} } } 
    ] },
    { $addToSet:{ 'books': DBRef( "book","168613_1671" ) } },
    { $not: { $exists:{ 'clientId': 168613, 'resourceId': 76864136 } } 
} );
```

so if in Bookmark collection, size of books is less than 3 then update the collection othewise check upsert which depends on whether there is any entry for a combination of clientId and resourceId.